# How Fill new List object in C# with values

Tags: c#

I have a phone object in C# that is returning (Home, work and phone Number) I like to fill another object with this values that has List of Phones that has Number and Type.
I write this code:

"patientUpdateInfo.phone" is the object that I am filling the phone:

```cs
private List<PhoneUpdateInfo> phones { get; set; } = new List<PhoneUpdateInfo>();

if (patientbyId.home_phone != null)
  { 
    foreach (var phone in phones)
    {
        phone.Number = patientbyId.home_phone;
        phone.Type = PhoneType.Home;
        patientUpdateInfo.Phones.Add(phone);
    }
}
```

and this in PhoneUpdateInfo object:

```cs
public class PhoneUpdateInfo
{
    public PhoneUpdateInfo()
    {
        Type = Data.PhoneType.Home;
    }
    public Data.PhoneType Type { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

my problem is this line:  foreach (var phone in phones) because the phone object is Empty( New object) it does not go inside the look to fill the object it will pass the foreach loop. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you only created a new List but not putting any data inside. It's like you get a box for putting toys, but you really didn't put any toys in the box. So the your list is the box, now you just need to put toys (instances of objects) in your list.

There are multiples ways to do this, but this is the two easy ways.

1- Initializing the list with values:

```
List<PhoneUpdateInfo> phones { get; set; } = new List<PhoneUpdateInfo>() 
{ 
    new PhoneUpdateInfo(), //first element
    new PhoneUpdateInfo(),  //second element
    AnyObjectAlreadyInstantiated //third element
};
```

2- Adding a element to a list with List.Add()

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    List<PhoneUpdateInfo> phones { get; set; } = new List<PhoneUpdateInfo>();
    phones.Add(new PhoneUpdateInfo());
    
    var instance = new PhoneUpdateInfo();
    phones.Add(instance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're approaching this backwards.  You're currently trying to loop over an empty list and repeatedly add the same information to it.  Even if the list did have records, `patientbyId` and `PhoneType.Home` don't change throughout your loop, so you'd just be overwriting *all* of those records with the same new record.

Instead, it looks like you just want to create a single object from that information and add it to the list.  Something like this:

```
if (patientbyId.home_phone != null)
{
    var phone = new PhoneUpdateInfo();
    phone.Number = patientbyId.home_phone;
    phone.Type = PhoneType.Home;
    phones.Add(phone);
}
```